# (#100) For field 'insights': period must be one of the following values: day, week, days_28, month, lifetime",

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day,

I have a problem when I try to get the metric values of facebook ads api.

I'm learning about the Facebook API and that's why I don't understand some things. I've tried in several ways, but nothing works.

This is my URL from graph API explorer: [Graph API Explorer 1](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/2169954096621238/insights/page_fans_city/EAAhZAgMuzLKgBAMEZASZAmTf5lPyMEV6ZAO3HhA3xm0PHs69ZBsJnlt4uCWC4RfJE2wvUtl06ecmayRqDHvcCnf92QcwOAAoGRWKTZAauMByG0X2RUqcPSrA4damZBwVLMfbooNvtQE1INduI1tKdQQOazcm2OYGgkN755lO1mna6350bNfNYTfEJONHCbO0ldPTE5d05OkuwZDZD/)

This is the error that throws me:

> (#100) For field 'insights': period must be one of the following values: day, week, days_28, month, lifetime

This is the graph API explorer link where my url is: [Graph API Explorer 2](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2169954096621238%2Finsights%2Fpage_fans_city%2FEAAhZAgMuzLKgBAMEZASZAmTf5lPyMEV6ZAO3HhA3xm0PHs69ZBsJnlt4uCWC4RfJE2wvUtl06ecmayRqDHvcCnf92QcwOAAoGRWKTZAauMByG0X2RUqcPSrA4damZBwVLMfbooNvtQE1INduI1tKdQQOazcm2OYGgkN755lO1mna6350bNfNYTfEJONHCbO0ldPTE5d05OkuwZDZD%2F&version=v3.3)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Insights docs here [Page Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/insights). Each metric has an additional period column that lists the available period for that specific metric. 
In your case (page_fans_city) it's `days` and therefore your call needs to include the period parameter like this

```
/me/insights/page_fans_city?period=day
```